# Display Subcategory WooCommerce products with titles

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I changed the display of woocommerce products to display as a table in the shop loop rather than columned elements. When i go to the 'shop' page it displays all products in a list though. I am having trouble display the products in an organized fashion separating the products into their corresponding sub categories. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
* @snippet       WooCommerce Show Product Subcategories
* @compatible    WooCommerce 3.4
*/

add_action( 
'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','bbloomer_show_all_subcats', 2 );

function bbloomer_show_all_subcats() {

// Create array with product categories that belong to current product

$cats = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

if ( ! empty( $cats ) ) {

// Loop through the product categories...

    foreach ( $cats as $term ) {

                    // If parent cat ID = 116 echo subcat name...
        if( $term->parent == 116 ) { echo $term->name; }

    }

    }

  }
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you! I ended up figuring it out. I was able to pull a <ul> of all the categories and subcategories with links to corresponding pages in a loop. From there i inserted in the loop to display that current categories products.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'parent'   => 0
);

$product_cat = get_terms( $args );

foreach ($product_cat as $parent_product_cat)
{
    if ($parent_product_cat->name != 'Company'){
    ?>

    <ul>
        <li><h2><a href='<?= get_term_link($parent_product_cat->term_id) ?>'><?= $parent_product_cat->name ?></a></h2>
            <hr align='left' width='50%'>
            <ul>

                <?php
                $child_args = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'hide_empty' => false,
                    'parent'   => $parent_product_cat->term_id
                );

                $child_product_cats = get_terms( $child_args );
                foreach ($child_product_cats as $child_product_cat)
                { ?>
                    <li style='padding-left: 2%;'>
                        <h3><a href='<?= get_term_link($child_product_cat->term_id) ?>'><?= $child_product_cat->name?></a></h3>
                    </li>
                    <div style='margin-left: -8%;'>
                        <?php
                        echo do_shortcode("[products category='$child_product_cat->term_id']");
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>

            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```